# Delete the oldest record from KDB table based on client pair match

Tags: kdb

I am looking to write a function to remove a row from the below table if the reverse client pair exists in the table (eg if cd1/cd2 has a cd2/cd1 matching pair)

I would like to remove the oldest record and keep the newest. To make it more clear I have included the table + the expected result

Table

```
flip (`dt`cd1`cd2`time`adj)!(2020.10.28 2020.10.28 2020.10.28 2020.10.28 2020.10.28 2020.10.28 2020.10.28;`ENC3`FA01`ENC4`STK2`STK1`RND3`TST5;`ENC4`FA02`ENC3`STK1`STK2`RND4`TST6;`s#2020.10.26T11:52:06.466 2020.10.26T12:52:06.466 2020.10.27T12:55:07.545 2020.10.27T16:08:34.051 2020.10.27T21:55:15.873 2020.10.28T12:59:06.466 2020.10.28T14:58:06.466;0.15 0.2 0.5 0.01 0.09 0.03 0.7)
```

Expected result below

```
flip (`dt`cd1`cd2`time`adj)!(2020.10.28 2020.10.28 2020.10.28 2020.10.28 2020.10.28;`FA01`ENC4`STK1`RND3`TST5;`FA02`ENC3`STK2`RND4`TST6;2020.10.26T12:52:06.466 2020.10.27T12:55:07.545 2020.10.27T21:55:15.873 2020.10.28T12:59:06.466 2020.10.28T14:58:06.466;0.2 0.5 0.09 0.03 0.7)
```

Really appreciate any input! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One way to keep the most recent row is:

```
select from t where time=(last;time) fby (asc each cd1,'cd2)
```

In above query rows are grouped by alphabetically sorted (cd1;cd2). Then row with the latest time is selected within each group. If table is not sorted by ascending time, replace `last` with `max`.

For deleting the oldest rows and keeping rest, e.g. when there are more than two rows with same instruments, use:

```
delete from t where ({(x=min x)&1<count x};time) fby (asc each cd1,'cd2)
```